# Alter URL #ID with JQuery button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function where, on every button click, the ID at the end of the pages URL is added to by 1. So,

example.org/page -> (buttonclick) -> example.org/page#1 -> (buttonclick) -> example.org/page#2 etc. etc.

What I've got at the moment is:

```
var anchor = 0;

$('#bottom-right').click(function() {
  var anchor += 1;
  var anchorurl = "#" + anchor;
  var currenturl = window.location.href;
  var newurl = currenturl.slice(0, -1) + anchorurl;
  window.location.replace(newurl);
});
```

But it doesn't really work & I imagine there is a cleaner solution...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply make it

```
$('#bottom-right').click(function() {
  window.location.hash = ++anchor;
});
```

Make use of the built-in `hash` method.

Comment: Great, so just to clarify if I were to put it into an html doc: it would look like       
`<script type="text/javascript">
        var anchor = 0;

    $('#bottom-right').click(function() {
     window.location.hash = ++anchor;
    });
      </script>

<div id="bottom-right"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/arrowdown.png" width="30px" height="30px"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

So basically the url contains `#`.So you can also track this `#` and get the next number and increment it.

Code example:

```
var hashValue = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf('#')+1);   
window.location.hash = hashValue + 1;
```